# How to make my program to behave like Dictionary in iBooks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, ibooks

When I use iBooks on Mac, and `highlight` a word with a mouse, English Thesaurus is shown:
[image]

I'd like my program to do similar thing - to appear like this Thesaurus in iBooks.
 How can it be reached? 
The simplest idea is recognizing that some text is selected, but maybe iBooks has some API (nothing useful at https://developer.apple.com/ibooks/).
 Or maybe Mac OS has event "single word selected", and I can subscribe for it.

What kind of app is best suited for that: `Cocoa App` or some extension/plugin?

I'm **not** interested in "long way" (context menu):
[image]

**Any advices will be highly appreciated, because I don't know anything about that.:)**

Comment: What is the question, how to detect the selection of text or how to show the thesaurus? How do you display the text? What did you try? Is [Supporting Contextual Lookup](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH5-SW2) of Dictionary Services what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are looking for is `NSView`'s `showDefinitionForAttributedString:atPoint:` method or one of its siblings. HTH